# Проблема с получением почты PHP IMAP rambler.ru

Tags: php, imap

Добрый день,

Подключил IMAP DLL к PHP 5.4.31(XAMPP, win XP), 
phpinfo> imap
IMAP c-Client Version   2007e
SSL Support     enabled

написал простенький код:

```
/*
Сервер: imap.rambler.ru
Шифрование: SSL (порт 993) или STARTTLS (порт 143)
*/
$user  = 'userxxxx@lenta.ru';
$pass = 'xxxxxx';
$connect = imap_open('{imap.rambler.ru:993}INBOX',$user, $pass);
if ($connect) {echo 'Successful';} else {echo 'Failed';}
```

результат:

> Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.rambler.ru:993}INBOX
>   in D:\Programs\Xampp\htdocs\post\posts.php on line 8
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in
>   D:\Programs\Xampp\htdocs\post\posts.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Unknown: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)
>   (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

т,е, код виснет, через 60 сек PHP выключает, доступ к почтовым программам в єккаунте ramblera включен, через сайт вхожу\выхожу моментально.

В чем может быть проблема ?

Если указываю несуществующий сервер то четко выдает: Host not found (#11001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте `imap_open('{imap.rambler.ru:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',$user, $pass}` по аналогии с гуглом. Аккаунта на рамблере не имею, но так получаю ошибку "Incorrect username/password" вместо бесконечного ожидания подключения.